# comparing value to the previous cell value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to compare multiple conditions to update the value of a cell. I want to compare the value of column 'open' to the next value in the same column and update a column 'high'. However, the column has to be updated only if the new value was higher than the previous value of 'high' column.
i.e. update 'high' column based on whether 'open' is higher than the next day's price and also the previous day's price
While I was able to do it using `iterrows`

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
     
     i1,row1 = next(df.iterrows())
     if((row['open'] > row1['open']) & (row['open'] > high)):
       high=row['open']
     if(row1['open'] > high):
        high=row1['open']
        
     if((row['open'] < row1['open']) & (row['open'] < low)):
       low=row['open']
     if(row1['open'] < high):
        low=row1['open']
```

I am having issues using numpy to do it efficiently

```
df['high']=np.where(df['open'] > df['open'].shift(), 
                    np.where(df['open'] > df['high'].shift(-1), df['open'], df['open'].shift()), 
                    df['open'].shift())
```

and keep getting `KeyError: 'high'`

Any suggestions?
| date               | open  |
| -------------------| ------|
| 2021-10-19 01:35:00| 2.135|
| 2021-10-19 01:34:00| 2.130|
| 2021-10-19 01:33:00| 2.129|
| 2021-10-19 01:32:00| 2.127|
| 2021-10-19 01:31:00| 2.130|
| 2021-10-19 01:30:00| 2.138|

[testdata][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YYQ3.png

Comment: Please add a sample of data as a codesnippet :)

Comment: @meti: added a data download file link

Comment: Check `df.columns`. Maybe there is a space character in the `high` column name.

Comment: Add data in the form which anybody can copy and past it, please! Asking a well-styled question increases the chance of getting a good answer

Comment: @meti : was unable to create a table. so, added sample data as an image test data is also present in the post, but it looks unaligned